# Time series forcasting in python

Tags: python

I have a series of data that which correspond to values for each day. The data is for 2 weeks and there is a pattern in which the last 2 days of the week have drops.

```
data=[2,4,6,8,10,1,1,3,5,8,11,10,2,1]
```

I need to develop a simple prediction model in python using this data to predict the values for next week. This model needs to consider seasonal data ( or patterns )

I've tried using the `pandas` library but cant get it to work.

If you can explain your mathematical model as well that would be great.

Comment: have a look at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/

Comment: For Time Series I would recommend [PyFlux](http://www.pyflux.com/docs/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

So here is an approach

`def runningSums(lst):
    s = 0
    for addend in lst:
        s += addend
        return s`

```
runningSums(data)
>>> 2
```

Which is the next possible value.

To obtain a list call `list` on the result of this function.

For more details [refer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134202/predict-the-next-number-in-any-sequence)